# Not allowing users to Add Duplicate values to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to prevent users from adding Duplicate values to a HTML Table based on the Month mentioned in the table when click add row Button. I tried with Following method, but it will always skip the first row when checking duplicate values. Image shows the error I'm getting with Duplicates.

[image]

**Method I tried.**

```
<select  id="month"  class="form-control">
  <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
  <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
  <option value="March">March</option>
  <option value="April">April</option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="amt5" />

<input type="button" class="btn" value="Add Row" onclick="ftm2add5()">

<table id="table5" class="table table-dark" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Select</th>
            <th scope="col">Month</th>
            <th scope="col">T/O Value</th>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none;">TORef</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


function ftm2add5() {
  var cat = $("#month").val();
  var amt = $("#amt5").val();

  var cate = $("#month option:selected").html();

  if (amt == "") {
    $("#amt5").addClass("red-border");
  } else {
    var allCells = $("#table5 tr td:nth-child(2)");
    var textMapping = {};
    allCells.each(function() {
      textMapping[$(this).text()] = true;
    });

    var count = 0;
    for (var text in textMapping) count++;

    if (count !== allCells.length) {
      alert("found duplicate values");
    } else {
      var markup =
        "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" +
        cate +
        "</td><td style='display:none;'>" +
        cat +
        "</td><td>" +
        amt +
        "</td></tr>";
      $("#table5 tbody").append(markup);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of building the dom directly, build an array of objects which represent your data, implement the add, update and delete operations on the array, then make method you call which renders the table, and then simply before adding an item check the array if it exists, also you could disable the select for the month which would be more obvious from ux point of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with a jquery selector:

```
$('#table5 tr:contains("' + cat +'")').length
```

```js
function ftm2add5() {
  var cat = $("#month").val();
  var amt = $("#amt5").val();
  
  var cate = $("#month option:selected").html();

  if (amt == "") {
    $("#amt5").addClass("red-border");
  } else {
    
    if ($('#table5 tr:contains("' + cat +'")').length > 0) {
      alert("found duplicate values");
    } else {
      var markup =
        "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" +
        cate +
        "</td><td style='display:none;'>" +
        cat +
        "</td><td>" +
        amt +
        "</td></tr>";
      $("#table5 tbody").append(markup);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="month"  class="form-control">
  <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
  <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
  <option value="March">March</option>
  <option value="April">April</option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="amt5" />

<input type="button" class="btn" value="Add Row" onclick="ftm2add5()">

<table id="table5" class="table table-dark" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Select</th>
            <th scope="col">Month</th>
            <th scope="col">T/O Value</th>
            <th scope="col" style="display:none;">TORef</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```